# 3d View layout closer

Tags: 3d-view

Is there any way to move some of the top items in the 3D View to the left? On my laptop they are covered when I have a layout including side views (Outliner on left and Properties on right.)

I usually have  to minimize one or the other to get the shaders selectors and the options drop down there to be visible. I have the Blenderkit "Find Models" in  the middle which I rarely use (but do want to keep) and wonder if I can move that elswehere, and would it move the shaders more leftwise if I could??

Answer (score 1):

See that little rounded corner where edges meet?
Hover over it, then click-and-drag it in whatever direction you want to create a new tab.

[image]

To remove a tab, right-click on that tiny darkened line that separates the tabs and select 'Join Areas'

[image]
[image]